# What's in the next-to-last room?

Tags: oddworld-abes-exoddus

So I recently played through Abe's Exoddus again, finally paying close enough attention to find all the secret areas and rescue everyone. However one thing I noticed that actually always bothered me: in the final level, after getting and using the Shrykull, you drop down *two* rooms. In the last room you rescue the final four slaves before escaping.

However in the room just before that, where you just fall straight through, there are four UXBs and more importantly an Abe Portal. There's an open trapdoor (that you fall through), which suggests that it could be closed, resulting in you needing to defuse the bombs and go through the portal.

[image: screenshot]

What's through there, and why is the door always open making the room seemingly useless?

Comment: Could you please post a screenshot if you have one? It might jog my memory.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. [Here you go](http://prntscr.com/1xj3o5)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Congratulations! You found the way to the bad ending! To get there, all you have to do is to save LESS than 150 Mudokons! Then you can witness what becomes of Abe, besides a heartless murderer and/or inefficient savior.

Comment: Well, that would explain why I've never seen the door closed XD I mean, 90 Mudokons in the Mines, plus 90 in the Brewery, that's already 180, never mind the 120 others in FeeCo and associated areas. Guess I'm just too good at this game for the bad ending :D